# how to get available quantity of Lot number

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10

how to get available quantity of Lot number in multiple warehouse

suppose i have 3 warehouse A,B and C,
Lot number LOT0001

i want sum of total currently availabel quantity of LOT0001 in all three location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In odoo you can pass filters in context.

ex:

context=**{'lot_id':'','owner_id':'','package_id':'','warehouse':'','force_company':'','location':''}**

**product.with_context(context).qty_available**

In odoo base module system will automatically calculate quantity based on context.

If you not pass context then system will give you sum of all warehouse stock.

this may help you.